# Переопределение класса

Tags: php, битрикс

Хочу переопределить метод `query()` класса `Facet()` умного фильтра. В `init.php` пишу:

```
class FacetMod extends \Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Facet  {
    public function query(array $filter, array $facetTypes = array(), $facetId = 0)
    {
        /*код */
    }    
}
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
Class '\Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Facet' not found in C:\Bitrix\www\bitrix\php_interface\init.php
```

Почему не находит этот класс не могу понять.

Answer (score 1):

Не был подключен сам модуль инфоблока: `\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule("iblock")`

Answer (score 0):

Может попробывать так

```
use \Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Facet

class FacetMod extends \Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Facet  {
  // you rewrite
}
```

Comment: не помогает, подключал уже `use Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Facet;
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
use Bitrix\Catalog;`

Comment: `class FacetMod extends Facet  {`

и попробуй так ещё. И посмотри в файле Facet.php как там называеться класс может в этом проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Советую не делать правок в файле `\Bitrix\www\bitrix\php_interface\init.php`.

Создавайте копию файла в `\Bitrix\www\local\php_interface\init.php`

Плюс ко всему, если вы хотите править сам класс, советую так-же делать всё через папку `/local`.

К примеру: `www\bitrix\modules\iblock\lib\propertyindex\ -> www\local\modules\iblock\lib\propertyindex\` и копируем сюда `facet.php` и уже внутри него правим `function query()`

Comment: Аргументируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Из-за обновлений битрикса, битрикс при обновлении трёт все файлы в папке /bitrix, если есть таковые в новой версии

Comment: не все файлы, в частности папка php_interface не затрагивается